# How to restart last conflict situation in rebase?

Tags: git, rebase

I rebase my 15 commits with master. Each my commit contains a lot of conflicts. I've successfully resolved conflicts in first six commits, but during resolved conflicts in the seven commit I made a big mistake. I don't want restart whole rebase process and also I don't now how to restart last my phase. 
How I can manage it?

I didn't find this question in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-m` flag for checkout, to ask for the unmerged version of a file during a merge (or rebase / cherry-pick, any potentially conflicting operation)

```
git checkout -m -- path/to/file
```

or even do this on the whole repo with

```
git checkout -m .
```

Doc is [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt--m) and [there](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt-emgitcheckoutemlttree-ishgt--ltpathspecgt82308203).

Comment: Will this revert the files to the state they were in before the conflict op wants to fix, (commit seven in this case), or to the state they were in before the rebase started?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness It'll revert the files to their *original conflicted state*, not the state *before* the conflict.

Comment: @ИванГладуш Anecdotically, your upvote/acceptance just made me a moderator :'-) *Champagne!*

Comment: @RomainValeri Thanks. By *original conflicted state* you refer to the state of the files before the seventh commit resolve was started?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Yes, that's what I meant. It resets the file to the last known conflicted state, if you prefer.

Comment: @RomainValeri Cool, thanks for the clarification. Congrats on the 10k ;)

Comment: @RomainValeri Congrats on the 10k. Let me know if you have other problems and ambitions  ;)